# Redis persistence on master slave configuration

Tags: redis

I have configured two slaves and one master using sentinel.
I have turned off persistence on all the servers. Now the sync happens between master and slave using BGSAVE command. 
So shall i assume that though i have persistence off redis is still persisting since it created rdb file for syncing data?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just have to use replication diskless to avoid Redis using BGSAVE. In fact diskless replication use socket instead of the file to send data on their slaves

https://deepsource.io/blog/redis-diskless-replication/

regard,